# Expresión regular sencilla

Tags: python, regex

Me da un poco de vergüenza la pregunta, pero no consigo solucionarlo por mi cuenta.

Tengo dos tipos de datos:

1.- Datos con país + espacio + información entre paréntesis. Ejemplo: Bolivia (Plurinational State of)

2.- País con el numero integrado. Ejemplo: Switzerland17

Simplemente necesito una expresión regular para quedarme solo con el nombre del país. Es decir, Bolivia y Switzerland.

Gracias como siempre.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es una cadena de solo letras al comienzo. La expresión es `[a-zA-Z]` para reconocer cualquier letra, mayúscula o minúscula. Para reconocer una secuencia de una o más letras, agregamos un "+" a la cola: `[a-zA-Z]+`.

Para capturar el país y tenerlo disponible, colocamos las expresión entre paréntesis, `([a-zA-Z]+)`.

Vamos a usar `match` para examinar la cadena. La función intenta calzar el patrón desde el comienzo de la cadena; si la cadena empieza con algo distinto a una letra, el calce falla. Si quisieras buscar el nombre en cualquier parte de la cadena, puedes usar `find` en lugar de `match`.

**Código**

```
import re

patron = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)")

texto = "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)"
m = patron.match(texto)
if m:
    pais = m.group(1)
    print(pais)

texto = "Switzerland17"
m = patron.match(texto)
if m:
    pais = m.group(1)
    print(pais)
```

produce:

```
Bolivia
Switzerland
```

Comment: La solución funciona, pero no sé muy bien como aplicarlo a mi situación. Estos datos los tengo en un pandas dataframe, y me gustaria aplicar la expresión regular a toda la columna.

Comment: @Rafael. Esa sería una nueva pregunta.